# Neumann boundary condition for strong degenerate problems

Tags: control-theory, parabolic-pde

In this article [1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225108299_Carleman_estimates_for_degenerate_parabolic_operators_with_applications_to_null_controllability), in (1.4), the authors say tha the natural boundary condition to the strong degenerate problem is of Neumann type. I couldn't find the reason. Can someone explain the reason or give me some reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best answer is given in the book [P. Cannarsa et al. Global Carleman Estimates for Degenerate Parabolic Operators](https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-239-1133/).

The degeneracy of the problem
$$
u_t - (a(x) u_x)_x = h \chi_\omega
$$
depends on $a(x)$.

If $\frac{1}{a} \in L^1(0, 1)$ we have *weakly degenerate operators*, if $\frac{1}{a} \notin L^1(0, 1)$ we have *strongly degenerate operators*.

For the weakly degenerate operators one can consider Dirihlet and Neumann boundary conditions. For the strongly degenerate operators the boundary conditions is
$$
\begin{cases}
a(x)u_x(t, x) \to 0 \mbox{ as } x \to 0^+ \\
u(t, 1) = 0
\end{cases}
$$

This boundary conditions is of Neumann type because we use $u_x(t, x)$. It was proved that the problem  is well-posed with given above boundary conditions and the solution belongs to suitable weighted Sobolev space.